# C# Error 'Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object'

Tags: c#, instance, object-reference

I've read other questions about this but don't see where or why my code is throwing this error. The code I have is below, if anyone can see where i'm going wrong.

```
    private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlConnectionNW.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
        try
        {
            sqlConnectionNW.Open();
            String enteredDate = cmbDay.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + cmbMonth.SelectedItem.ToString() + "/" + cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if ((txtEmployeeID.TextLength != 0) && (enteredDate.Length != 0))
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);
                employeesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID ='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "'";
                String birthDate;
                birthDate = dsEmployees.Employees.FindByEmployeeID(ID).BirthDate.ToShortDateString();

                if (employeesBindingSource.Count > 0)   //GETS TO HERE AND THEN GOES TO CATCH EX
                {
                    sqlConnectionNW.Close();
                    if (enteredDate.ToString() == birthDate.ToString())
                    {
                        frmMenu frmMainMenu = new frmMenu();
                        frmMainMenu.server = server;
                        frmMainMenu.employeeID = txtEmployeeID.Text;
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the Northwind Ordering System");
                        this.Hide();
                        frmMainMenu.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The birth date you have entered is incorrect");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The Employee ID you have entered does not exist");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        sqlConnectionNW.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Do you know which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Jon, how is the compiler going to help in finding the cause of a runtime exception?

Comment: Have edited post to show where the error occurs.

Comment: @Kirk: My bad. For some reason was thinking exception message (=stack trace) and converted that to compiler error message. Sorry :)

Comment: @Kimmy, that line could not possibly have been the direct cause of this, since the only candidate for an NRE (`employeesBindingSource`) was dereferenced earlier.  Thus, what is `employeesBindingSource` to begin with?  Possibly the implementation of `Count` is throwing the error.  Can you please post the entire stack trace?

Comment: @Kimmy25 Can you please post how you define/initialise the variable "employeesBindingSource".

Comment: This may sounds strange but nothing appears in the Call Stack window :S

Comment: I just added it to the Windows Form and connected it etc in the properties window.

Comment: @Kimmy25 So are you saying the employeesBindingSource is a component? (Dragged from the Toolbox onto the Design window?)

Comment: Can't you put a breakpoint at the first line of that method and then single-step to see exactly where the error occurs?  Before executing each line, use the debugger to examine every variable that will be used. I think you'll find the error fairly quickly that way.

Comment: which line you are getting an exception?

Answer (score 2):

Manage to solve this problem. I changed this:

```
if ((txtEmployeeID.TextLength != 0) && (enteredDate.Length != 0))
            {

                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);

                employeesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID ='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "'";

                String birthDate;

                birthDate = dsEmployees.Employees.FindByEmployeeID(ID).BirthDate.ToShortDateString();    // FROM HERE

                if (employeesBindingSource.Count != 0)
                {

                    sqlConnectionNW.Close();
```

To this:

if ((txtEmployeeID.TextLength != 0) && (enteredDate.Length != 0))
                {

```
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmployeeID.Text);

                employeesBindingSource.Filter = "EmployeeID ='" + txtEmployeeID.Text + "'";

                String birthDate;

                if (employeesBindingSource.Count != 0)
                {
                    birthDate = dsEmployees.Employees.FindByEmployeeID(ID).BirthDate.ToShortDateString();    //TO HERE

                    sqlConnectionNW.Close();
```

It was just a case of putting the "birthDate = ..." after the if statement.